# how to use bloom-redis in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, bloom-filter

I need to use bloom filter backed with redis in nodejs for checking duplicates in a stream of data. For this purpose I have been using bloom-redis package of nodejs. But the documentation is not at all helpful. I'm not able to understand how to check that an element is present in the filter or not using the contains function using callback. I have gone through the code of bloom-redis package and I tried to print what the callback parameter prints when an element is present in filter and when the element is not present. Unfortunately, the callback parameters are same in both the cases( val= null, isAbsent=true). SO how can I check the presence of an element?

---

Below is my code where I have tried to check the presence of an element:

```
bloom = require('bloom-redis');

var client = redis.createClient();
bloom.connect(client);

filter = new bloom.BloomFilter({ key : 'mykey',
size:0.002,
numHashes:5 });


filter.add("sam")
filter.add("richa")
filter.contains("element-that-is-not-presnet",function(val,isAbsent){
    console.log(val) //return null
    console.log(isAbsent) //returns true
})

filter.contains("richa",function(val,isAbsent){
    console.log(val) //returns null
    console.log(isAbsent) //returns true
})
```

Comment: Did you check redisbloom.io?

Comment: Yes, it's not of much help

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/albert-team/rebloom?

Comment: Did you find solution to this?